# Скрипт обрезки пробелов

Tags: jquery, php, javascript

Привет.

Следующая функция считает количество символов, введенных в поле:

```
function validateComments(input) {
       if (input.value.length < 15) {
          input.setCustomValidity("Длина примечания не должна составлять менее 15 символов.");   
       }
       else {
          // Длина комментария отвечает требованию, 
          // поэтому очищаем сообщение об ошибке
          input.setCustomValidity("");
       }
}
```

Но она учитывает также и пробелы, как это можно убрать? Пожалуйста, покажите. )

Comment: Нет такого слова "состов". Пробелы не надо убирать, их не надо считать. Кроме пробелов, существует целый ряд непечатных символов, из которых целиком можно составить для вас комментарий, и вы его примите.

Answer (score 2):

```
input.value.replace(/\s+/g, '')
```

Должно удалить все пробелы в строке.

Answer (score 1):

[[@Alextrue](/users/23784/alextrue)](/users/23784/alextrue), учтите, что функция replace не изменяет исходную строку, а возвращает новую.

```
function fn (input) {
  var l = input.value.replace(/^\s*|\s*$/g, '').replace(/\s+/, ' '); // оставляем по пробелу между словами, если надо.
  ...
}
```